# Web Socket Protocol Handshake vs. Switching Protocols

Tags: http, websocket, http-headers

What's the difference between these two response statuses:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake

HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
```

Does it matter which one I get?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is no difference whatsoever.  What is important is the `101` response code to indicate the handshake is progressing.  This is defined in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455):

> The leading line from the client follows the Request-Line format. **The leading line from the server follows the Status-Line format**.  The Request-Line and Status-Line productions are defined in [RFC2616].
>
> ...
>
> The handshake from the server is much simpler than the client handshake.  **The first line is an HTTP Status-Line**, with the status code 101:
>
> HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
>
> Any status code other than 101 indicates that the WebSocket handshake has not completed and that the semantics of HTTP still apply.

The text of the `Status-Line` is arbitrary, the server can use whatever text it wants, per [RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616):

> Status-Line = HTTP-Version SP Status-Code SP **Reason-Phrase** CRLF
>
> ...
>
> The Status-Code element is a 3-digit integer result code of the attempt to understand and satisfy the request. These codes are fully defined in section 10. The Reason-Phrase is intended to give a short textual description of the Status-Code. The Status-Code is intended for use by automata and **the Reason-Phrase is intended for the human user. The client is not required to examine or display the Reason-Phrase.**

`Switching Protocols` just happens to be what the examples in [RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455) use, but that is not a requirement.