# Making xampp and node(socket.io) work together

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a little web app which applies some AngularJS and php for some functions and some queries from the database(xampp's Apache and mySQL). Now I want to apply to a simple chat in the web app and I do not know how to configure nor what ports and so on.

Following something similar to http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

I have index.js  as such

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');

});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
   console.log('a user connected');
   socket.on('disconnect', function(){
   console.log('user disconnected');
   });
});


http.listen(443, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:443');
});
```

I am trying port 443 and 80, but they doesnt seem to work (xampp shows 80 and 443, no idea how ports work)

my JS file then has  `var socket = io();`

In my browser console , I'm getting something like

```
socket.io-1.2.0.js:2 GET http://localhost/socket.io/?IO=3&transport=polling&t=1465649664392-0 404 (Not Found)
```

How do I resolve this problem? I am expecting output such as `a user connected` in the cmd after running `node index.js` but I do not.

I followed the example for the chat, and it works fine without xampp.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that for `socket.io` to work it needs to be able to communicate with the back end over http (e.g. to [switch the protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22418369/6430127)). But if xampp is using the port it won't work. You could probably try something where your xampp forwards requests to `http://localhost/socket.io/*` to the `node.js` server.

You can use the [ProxyPass directive in the Apache httpd.conf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18604082/6430127) and do something like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/socket.io            [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket    [NC]
RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:8000/$1 [P,L]

ProxyPass        /socket.io http://localhost:8000/socket.io
ProxyPassReverse /socket.io http://localhost:8000/socket.io
```

Also make sure that the required modules are enabled

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_wstunnel_module modules/mod_proxy_wstunnel.so
```

Then you'd have to start the `node.js` server on port `8000`

```
http.listen(8000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:8000');
});
```

Comment: Do I just put the directive anywhere in the config file? and do I access xampp normally such as `localhost/foldername` ?

Comment: You do everything normally. You add the directive anywhere in the `httpd.conf`. I added it at the end of the file.

Comment: Can I have your example? I did everything you said and nothing changed ( I probably lack the knowledge around these stuff)

Comment: My `apache/conf/httpd.conf` is http://pastebin.com/ruihe9GR. You probably can't coppy the entire file because of the absolute paths in there. My `main.js` file is this http://pastebin.com/CTfgNJmS. I run it with `node main.js`. My `index.php` file is http://pastebin.com/YWh7haPF. I have this file in `htdocs/php-test/index.php`. I access the example in my browser under `http://localhost/php-test/`. I'm using the windows version of xampp under windows 10. Oh and you need to restart apache after changing `httpd.conf`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this and no need for any http redirects
open your client side js

```
var configUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';// currently my node js using this port
var socket = io(configUrl);
```

and remaining things works smoothly in your client side

```
socket.emit('chatMessage', ...
socket.on('chatMessage', ..
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use scoket.io client library, so we can use JavaScript as client and node.js as server.

Please checkout below example:

index.html(client)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello world</title>
  <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.0.1/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    var socket = io('http://localhost:5000');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js (Node.js server)

```
var io=require('socket.io')(5000,{
  cors:{
    origin: "http://localhost",
  },
});


//Whenever someone connects this gets executed
io.on('connection',socket => {
 console.log('A user connected');
});
```